# nosetests opens a dialogue box when run after installing nose

Tags: python, powershell, nosetests

I'm on exercise 46 of Learn Python the Hard Way, and I'm meant to install nose and run nosetests. I've installed nose already using pip, but when I run nosetests in the directory above the 'tests' folder, I get a small pop out dialog box asking me to specify a program to use in openning some file I don't know. I'm on windows 7 and I use powershell

Comment: Can you post the directory structure and the actual error messsage?

Comment: Directory: C:\Users\IKIKIN\Documents\python\projects\skeleton, this is the structure and I dont get any errors just a small dialogue box pops up asking me to choose a program with which to use to open a file or something windows is attempting to open.